# adding an index to sql server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a query that gets run often.  its a dynmaic sql query because the sort by changes.

```
SELECT userID, ROW_NUMBER(OVER created) as rownumber
from users
where
  divisionID = @divisionID and isenrolled=1
```

the OVER part of the query can be:

- userid
- created

Should I create an index for:

- divisionID + isenrolled
- divisionID + isenrolled + each_sort_by_option ?

Where should I put indexes for this table?

Comment: I would try to avoid too many indices - that can be just as bad as no indices! An index hopefully speeds up SELECT's - but at the same time, there's a perf penalty on INSERTs and DELETEs (and potentially UPDATEs). Be careful not to over-index your tables! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with

```
CREATE INDEX IX_SOQuestion ON dbo.users (divisionID, isenrolled) INCLUDE (userID, created)
```

- The `created` ranking is unrelated to the WHERE clause, so may as well just INCLUDE it (so it's covered) rather that in the key columns. An internal sort would be needed anyway, so why make the key bigger?
- Other sort columns could be included too
- `userid` is only needed for output, so INCLUDE it
- perhaps take isenrolled into INCLUDE if it's bit. Only 2 states (OK, 3 with NULL), so kinda pointless to add to the key columns

Answer (score 0):

Start with `divisionID + isenrolled + userID` as it will always be used